# Notify a web browser, which protocol server is using

Tags: java, browser, http2

As a Proxy Program sitting in between Server and Browser , how can we notify a browser to use either http1.1 or http2.0 protocol

Comment: more specs please (what did u tried already, what do you have, etc.)

Comment: why not write this logic in javascript?

Comment: More specifically , I have java program that act like a proxy will read requests from browser and send to server , so it is an intermediate component. In case of http2.0 for https websites we need to do ALPN negotiation. That is working completely as my proxy component read the request (default will be http1.1) from browser and send to server with ALPN protocol. But the problem is if the server support also ALPN protocol h2 , how can I inform back the browser that , from next onwards you have to upgrade your communication from http1.1 to http2 protocol

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether your "proxy" is a forward proxy configured on the browser, or a reverse proxy configured on the server.

In the first case (forward proxy), because the target scheme is `https`, the browser will issue a HTTP `CONNECT` to the forward proxy and the forward proxy will create a tunnel to the server.
Once the tunnel is created, the browser and the server will communicate directly with the forward proxy only forwarding bytes in both directions.

In this case, client and server will negotiate directly the protocol via ALPN because they communicate directly, with the forward proxy only forwarding bytes (but not inspecting or otherwise changing them).

Therefore in this case you don't need to inform the client of anything, because client and server communicate directly.

In the second case (reverse proxy) the browser will connect to the reverse proxy thinking it's its final destination.
For a request to https://example.com, the DNS will resolve the reverse proxy address, and the reverse proxy must offer a valid certificate for example.com.

If the reverse proxy needs to forward the request to a server, then it does not matter what protocol it will use, since the client will never be aware of this communication between the reverse proxy and the server.

If the reverse proxy supports only HTTP/1.1 and the server supports HTTP/2, then the reverse proxy cannot tell the client that the server supports HTTP/2 because the client never talks directly to the server: the client only sees the reverse proxy and because the reverse proxy only supports HTTP/1.1 then they will never be able to speak HTTP/2, even if the server does.

If the reverse proxy supports both HTTP/1.1 and HTTP/2, then the client and the reverse proxy will speak HTTP/2. It does not matter what protocol the reverse proxy speaks to the server: it can be HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, FastCGI, etc. But the protocol that the reverse proxy uses with the server is of no interest to the client because the client will never be able to talk directly to the server.

The client only ever speaks to the reverse proxy, so the protocol that they negotiate is the only one that matters to the client.

In this case also you don't need to inform the client of anything, because the client can only communicate with the proxy and can only use the protocol that it negotiated with the proxy.

Comment: Ok , but after the connect, the Proxy Program is replying to the client 200 ok and then doing all the steps like DNS resolution, network connection and then the handshake with ALPN. After this step if you try to read the client input stream still you are getting the HTTP1.1 request , not the HTTP2.0 frames.

Comment: The proxy is replying to the client with a 200 using HTTP/1.1, so the communication with the client is HTTP/1.1. If the proxy does all the steps like DNS, TCP connect and TLS handshake with ALPN with _the server_ that is irrelevant for the communication with the client.

Comment: So How can reply to client that server support http2.0 then ?

Comment: You cannot. You have to drop this idea of "telling the client what protocol the server speaks". The client only ever speaks to the proxy, never to the server.